# Dude, where's my object? or, Why does Linq not return my object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Once I have the results of my Linq query, I am not always happy. There could be a result that I was expecting to be there but wasn't. For example, my client was expecting that a customer was in a customer list, but it wasn't. It is my client saying "Dude, where's my customer?", not me. I am the Dude, and to remain a dude, I have to give my client the reason.

**Is there a simple way to take a given object instance and a Linq query and determine which expressions within the query excluded that instance?**

**Edit** Ok, here is a better example

Output should be something along the lines:

> Your Customer was excluded for 2 reasons:
>
> Customer FirstName is Carl but it should be Daniel
>
> Customer Age is 18 but it should be > 20

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Dude_wheres_my_object_test1()
    {
        var daniel = new Customer { FirstName = "Daniel", Age = 41 };
        var carl =  new Customer {  FirstName = "Carl", Age= 18 };
        var Customers = new List<Customer>() { daniel, carl };

        // AsQueryable() to convert IEnumerable<T> to IQueryable<T> in 
        //the case of LinqtoObjects - only needed for this test, not 
        //production code where queies written for LinqToSql etc normally 
        //return IQueryable<T>
        var query = from c in Customers.AsQueryable()
                    where c.Age > 20
                    where c.FirstName == "Daniel"
                    select c;
        //query would return Daniel as you'd expect, but not executed here.

        //However I want to explain why Carl was not in the results

        string[] r = DudeWheresMyObject(query, carl);
        Assert.AreEqual("Age is 18 but it should be > 20", r[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("FirstName is Carl but it should be Daniel", r[1]);


        //Should even work for a Customer who is not 
        //in the original Customers collection...
        var ficticiousCustomer = new Customer { FirstName = "Other", Age = 19};
        string[] r2= DudeWheresMyObject(query, 
                                         ficticiousCustomer);
        Assert.AreEqual("Age is 19 but it should be > 20", r2[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("FirstName is Other but it should be Daniel", r2[1]);
    }

    public string[] DudeWheresMyObject<T>(IQueryable<T> query, T instance)
    {
        //Do something here with the query.Expression and the instance

    }
```

First of all, before I attempt to write some fancy Fluent framework, **Has anyone done this already?**

So far, I have considered navigating the expression tree and executing each branch against an IQueryable that only contains my object. Now I don't have a great deal of experience using raw expression trees, so I would like those who have to suggest any pitfalls or even explain whether this is a dead end and why.

I am anxious that anything that results from this should:

- Be Reusable - Should be applicable to any object compared against a Linq query returning objects of the same class.
- Not affect the performance of the original query (this should just be standard Linq).
- Should be Linq-implementation agnostic.
- If there are multiple property values set on the missing instance that excluded it from the results, then all of those reasons should be reported.

**Edit**
I am not suggesting that I keep executing LinqToSql against the database multiple times with different permutations of the query and comparing the results. Rather, I am looking for a way to take a single instance and compare it to the expression tree (without executing the query directly again)

Also, I would like an indication of whether others might find this useful. If so, I would consider starting an open source project to solve it.

Comment: I'm not really following what you mean by "determine which expressions within the query excluded that instance".  If an expression explicitly excludes an instance, don't you know that already?  Since you deliberately excluded it?

Comment: Ok, I thought I wasn't clear enough. I'll update with an example shortly

Comment: Might be tough with linq to [anything that isn't objects] as presumably you'd need to run a query with no restrictions (or less and less restrictions) which could hit the db hard, depending on the number of rows. Nice idea though. Maybe you'd get around that if you ran another query to get the specific object you want to test against and only look at that object and the where clauses (maybe that's your original idea).

Comment: This wont work. Seriously. How would that Framework deal with a table of a Million entries that return 20? Analyze the rest - have fun with that. Does not exist for SQL for the same reason.

Comment: Exactly George. I don't think I was clear enough. I wouldn't imagine running the second part of it in the database but through LinqToObjects.  I would retrieve the instance that I was expecting through other means and then compare it to the query

Comment: There is no way (that i'm aware of) to determine what records an Expression tree might exclude without actually executing the query.  Or, at least any method you might use is likely to be far less efficient than executing the query.

Comment: "I wouldn't imagine running the second part of it in the database but through LinqToObjects." -- Then you won't get the same results. When you evaluate an expression tree through L2O, it will be evaluated according to .NET rules. When an expression tree is translated to SQL, it may, and almost always does, have subtle differences. For example, `from a in x where a.Object.Property == 3` won't translate to SQL that raises a `NullReferenceException` when `a.Object == null`. For another example, `from a in x where a.Property == y` won't work when `y` is `null`.

Comment: Thanks hvd. Those are the kind of pitfalls I am looking for. Any ideas of how to make this work, or even whether you would find something like this useful?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to reliably do this without performing a whole lot of different queries, sorry. But it would be nice if I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Do you need to run it at runtime as part of application? Or only during debuging? I'm sure it could be possible to hack LINQ to allow during debugging, but it could be huge performance hit during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some fun expression hacking, you can see the results of each stage of the evaluation for each item in the set. Inspect the local `result` after the breakpoint has been hit to see the results of the evaluation.  To actually use the results of the evaluation, just append `.Where(x => x.IsIncludedInResult).Select(x => x.EvaluationTarget)` to the line where the report is generated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Condition} on {EvaluationTarget} is {EvaluationResult}")]
    public class ReportItem<T>
    {
        public string Condition { get; private set; }

        public IEnumerable<ReportItem<T>> NestedReports { get; private set; }

        public object EvaluationResult { get; private set; }

        public T EvaluationTarget { get; private set; }

        public ReportItem(Expression condition, IEnumerable<ReportItem<T>> nestedReports, T evaluationTarget, object evaluationResult)
        {
            Condition = condition.ToString();
            NestedReports = nestedReports;
            EvaluationTarget = evaluationTarget;
            EvaluationResult = evaluationResult;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} on {1} is {2}", Condition, EvaluationTarget, EvaluationResult);
        }
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("Included: {IsIncludedInResult} \n{Summary}")]
    public class Report<T>
    {
        public ReportItem<T> Contents { get; private set; }

        public T EvaluationTarget { get; private set; }

        public Report(T source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            EvaluationTarget = source;

            IsIncludedInResult = predicate.Compile()(source);

            Contents = Recurse(predicate.Parameters.Single(), predicate.Body, source);
        }

        private object Evaluate(Expression expression, ParameterExpression parameter, T source)
        {
            var expr = Expression.Lambda(expression, parameter);
            var @delegate = expr.Compile();
            var value = @delegate.DynamicInvoke(source);
            return value;
        }

        private ReportItem<T> Recurse(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression sourceExpression, T source)
        {
            var constantExpression = sourceExpression as ConstantExpression;

            if(constantExpression != null)
            {
                return new ReportItem<T>(sourceExpression, null, source, Evaluate(constantExpression, parameter, source));
            }

            var unaryExpression = sourceExpression as UnaryExpression;

            if(unaryExpression != null)
            {
                var content = Recurse(parameter, unaryExpression.Operand, source);
                var result = Evaluate(sourceExpression, parameter, source);
                return new ReportItem<T>(sourceExpression, new[]{content}, source, result);
            }

            var binaryExpression = sourceExpression as BinaryExpression;

            if(binaryExpression != null)
            {
                var left = Recurse(parameter, binaryExpression.Left, source);
                var right = Recurse(parameter, binaryExpression.Right, source);
                var item = new ReportItem<T>(sourceExpression, new[] {left, right}, source, Evaluate(sourceExpression, parameter, source));
                return item;
            }

            var methodCallExpression = sourceExpression as MethodCallExpression;

            if(methodCallExpression != null)
            {
                var args = methodCallExpression.Arguments.Select(x => Evaluate(x, parameter, source)).ToArray();
                var result = methodCallExpression.Method.Invoke(Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression.Object, parameter).Compile().DynamicInvoke(source), args);
                return new ReportItem<T>(sourceExpression, null, source, result);
            }

            throw new Exception("Unhandled expression type " + sourceExpression.NodeType + " encountered");
        }

        public bool IsIncludedInResult { get; private set; }

        public string Summary
        {
            get { return Contents.ToString(); }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Summary;
        }
    }

    public static class PredicateRunner
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Report<T>> Report<T>(this IEnumerable<T> set, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return set.Select(x => new Report<T>(x, predicate));
        }
    }

    class MyItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value % 2;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name: \"{0}\" Value: {1}", Name, Value);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var items = new MyItem[3];
            items[0] = new MyItem
            {
                Name = "Hello",
                Value = 1
            };

            items[1] = new MyItem
            {
                Name = "Hello There",
                Value = 2
            };
            items[2] = new MyItem
            {
                Name = "There",
                Value = 3
            };

            var result = items.Report(x => !x.Name.Contains("Hello") && x.GetHashCode() == 1).ToList();
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It looks very promising. Pity I am too snowed under at work to take this further right now, but I will try this soon and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have to re-create the query as linq-to-objects and deal with the subtle differences between linq-to-sql/entities/whatever and linq-to-objects, accepting that some providers just won't work realistically.

You have your object you want to find in an in memory `IEnumerable<T>` or something.

You'd have to walk the expression tree somehow and snip out the leaves, so say you had:

```
where obj.foo == true && obj.bar == "yes"
```

you'd have to figure out that `obj.foo == true` and `obj.bar == "yes"` are leaves and start there. It'd be a sort of depth first search of the expression tree.

So, construct linq to objects queries that only had those leaves. See if the object is included in the results. If not then we've found out why it's excluded, if not then go up the tree (i.e. make the where query include more clauses, getting closer to the orignal one until the object disappears from the results).

As I see it the tough parts would be handling the differences between original linq to 'whatever' and link to objects, figuring out where to split the where claues, dealing with things like joins which can also exclude things and dealing with things like `SqlMethods.Like` that don't work in linq to objects.

Comment: Thanks George, that is certainly the kind of thing that I had in mind. You have explained it better than I did.

Answer (score 2):

For a one-off exploration of what's filtering out the result, it's hard to beat the `Dump` method in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net). Here's an extract from one of their samples that shows it in action:

```
// Dump returns exactly what it was given, so you can sneakily inject
// a Dump (or even many Dumps) *within* an expression. This is useful
// for monitoring a query as it progresses:

new[] { 11, 5, 17, 7, 13 }  .Dump ("Prime numbers")
.Where (n => n > 10)        .Dump ("Prime numbers > 10")
.OrderBy (n => n)           .Dump ("Prime numbers > 10 sorted")
.Select (n => n * 10)       .Dump ("Prime numbers > 10 sorted, times 10!");
```

This gives nicely formatted tables of results:

[image: LINQPad results]

Comment: +1 for mentioning this great feature of LinqPad. I will definitely make good use of this. However, I am looking for something that would be useable at runtime in my business layer.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a tricky one, as in, from your example you could always code something to check for specifics and report 'I searched for term x and the object i returned was not in term x'.

I would have though as others suggested though, that this would have been along the lines for 'return me x' then in code, run a query for 'x where x.property = y' and report non matches.

Following this through, I'd imagine the issue would be that in order to generate the list of non matches, your query or object graph would become pretty massive as you'd need your original object either initially include (or to be expanded via lazy loading to include) many permutations to determine the matches or not.

This is kind of the inverse of running a query on the first place where you'd start with an object and sub select based on conditions, you'd want to select and then selectively super select, catching non conditions.

It's an interesting problem, and one that I'd normally address either client side or code wise before getting to a point where and object was returned or not. But I guess the perfect solution would be to return a single solution and perhaps examine it's associations for links. 
The links wouldn't be too hard to find a generic "I've not got one of these" type reason, but to give a 'I've got this link, not that link' response would be harder.

You'd need to maybe provide a method based on some form of predicate builder which took a field and search term and returned an appropriate message if things didn't match. In my mind seems like two slightly different problems.

Slightly rambling now, but would be curious to hear any answers to this!...

Comment: Interesting that you mentioned a Predicate Builder. I did consider using FluentValidation for this, but that would require me writing Validators for each of my Linq Queries and passing the object through these validators. In the short term I might do this anyway

Answer (score -1):

I think I follow what you mean.  What I think you would want to do is perform two queries, one with selection criteria, and one without, then perform a Linq Except on them to determine which items were excluded, then walk that list and determine what criteria caused them to be excluded.

I can't really think of a better way to do it.

Something like this:

```
var a = db.Trades.Where(z => z.user == x && z.date == y);

var b = a.Where(z => z.TradeCurrency != null && z.TradeUnderlying.Index != null);

var c = a.Except(b);

List<string> reasons;
foreach(var d in c) {
    if (d.TradeCurrency == null)
        // add reason
    ... etc..
}
```

This would perform a single query (which would have several sub-queries) and only return the results that were excluded (rather than trying to return all results which could be quite large).  Unless of course you have a million excluded records and only a few included ones.

Not sure how efficient this is, though compared to a way I can't think of.

**EDIT:**

I think you are forgetting that Linq queries do not execute until you call an operation that realizes them.  In this example, the database is only hit once, even though there are several linq query objects here.  The expression tree is modified without executing the queries.

So in this example, when the `foreach()` occurs, a single database query (with several sub-queries) is executed.

Comment: I really only want to hit the database twice. Once with the original query. This would be dealt with in my application in the normal way and then discarded. The second time would be to get a single instance of the object that I expected to be returned in the original query but wasn't. Then I am looking for an in-memory way to compare the object to the query, without executing the query again, to get to the reason for the exclusion.

Comment: @DanielDyson - You can accomplish that by simply doing this:  `var c = a.Except(b).ToEnumerable();`, then when walking the list of exceptions it's done in memory, but be careful because if your exclude list is large, it could run out of memory (not to mention take a long time to transfer all data into memory).  Either way, though, you only hit the database once (remember, linq queries don't execute until you call an operation that causes the query to execute, in this case the `foreach()`)